# Example of an irreducible Markov Chain with a convergent subsequence

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I would like to know an example of an irreducible aperiodic Markov Chain $\{X_n\}$ such that $\{X_{n_k}\}$ converges in distribution. However it should not be the case that $X_n$ also converges in distribution.

So I basically want a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $p^{(n_k)}(i,j)$ converges as $k\to\infty$ to some $\pi(i,j)$ for all $i,j$ such that $\sum_j \pi(i,j)=1$ for each $i$ but $p^{(n)}(i,j)$ does not converge.

I could not get any example for this.

Comment: Try a periodic finite chain.

Comment: Thanks Did. But is there an example with an aperiodic irreducible Markov chain? That is the one I am interested about. I had thought that it is sufficient to consider irreducibility alone so did not mention aperiodicity in the question. Clearly I am wrong.

Comment: This is a rather strange question: have you never met any result about the behaviour of $p^{(n)}(i,j)$ when $n\to\infty$, for irreducible aperiodic finite Markov chains?

Comment: For ergodic Markov chains $p^{(n)}(i,j)$ converges to the unique stationary distribution. So that case is out of question. For null recurrent and transient markov chains, again $p^{(n)}(i,j)\to0$ for all $i,j$  so for any subsequence $p^{(n_k)}(i,j)\to0$ also. Right? But if the Markov Chain is tight, then we can have a subsequence converging in distribution. I am interested in these subsequences which converge in distribution. See the original chain may not converge in distribution.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea which remaining case you have in mind.

Comment: I want weak convergence of a subsequence, not the whole Markov Chain. The chain has to be irreducible, aperiodic. Editing the question to introduce "aperiodic". I also couldn't find any example. However, I thought like this: take a null recurrent irreducible aperiodic MC. Then I know there is no stationary distribution. But if the Markov chain is tight, we know by Helly-Bray that there is a weakly convergent subsequence. I am trying to get hold of that subsequence. I am looking for example of such chains where such a subsequence is known.

Comment: ?? If the chain is null recurrent, then $p^{(n)}(i,j)\to0$ for every fixed $(i,j)$. Hence $p^{(n_k)}(i,j)\to0$ for every subsequence $(n_k)$. Period.